# Why these two songs sound similar?

Tags: drums, melody, tempo

I'm not a music theory expert but found two songs that sound suspiciously similar and no information on the internet as to why, when or even *if* a major artist intentionally tried to pay homage or elegantly remix a song by a lesser known group. I'd like to know if the songs are indeed similar or if it is only my deceived perception. The songs in question are [Contact by Daft Punk, starting at ~1:46,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI5noh4OyXc) and [When the Catholic Girls Go Camping by Giraffes? Giraffes!, starting at ~0:11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZqZCS0rCmE).

Aren't the drum tempos and melodic progression the same in some sections of the songs? Are these songs close enough to consider Contact inspired or copied from When the Catholic Girls Go Camping?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in retrospect, the question doesn't fit this site. It would have been better on MusicFans, but is now too old to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

The Giraffes? Giraffes! recording was released before the Daft Punk recording, but that doesn't necessarily tell us when either was written.

To me the obvious difference is with meters. Giraffes? Giraffes! mixes meters, but the Daft Punk stays in 4/4 time.

It's hard to compare the tempos with different meters, but the Giraffes? Giraffes! track feels faster to me.

They both have a kind of arpeggiated figure that moves upward, quickly, with an even rhythm. I think they both start on a minor chord, but they aren't exactly the same.

Was Daft Punk inspired by Giraffes? Giraffes! (?) Maybe. Did they copy the music?... The Daft Punk song uses a I V vi IV progression over and over which makes it seems pointless to talk about melodies and progressions. This kind of musical material is used in hundreds on songs. This music is about rhythm and sound production, not original melodic and harmonic ideas, and on those points the two tracks seem very different to me.

Personally, I am familiar with the Giraffes? Giraffes! track, but not the Daft Punk, and I prefer the one by Giraffes? Giraffes! Nevertheless, I don't think the Daft Punk track is a rip off.